# Why Content frame is introduced into Touch UI

Tags: aem

In Touch UI, there is an iFrame called Content frame is added.
Can you please tell me

1. what is the reason of having an iFrame to display the page during the authoring?
2. There is an observer (/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/editors/clientlibs/internal/page/js/observe.js) which observes the changes made to the DOM and sends post message accordingly.
   What is the reason of sending postmessage and how this is helping?

Answer (score 0):

The AEM developers realized that many problems arose from the fact that edit UI and WYSIWYG content view were rendered into the same context in Classic UI:

- Edit UI would push content around, thus making it less WYSIWYG
- Content styles could interfere with edit UI, accidentally misplace or hide it
- Editor scripts could interfere with content scripts, meaning website authors would need to code around that
- Edit UI inserts additional HTML element which need to be accounted for in content stylesheets and scripts

Which is why they decided on a better approach for Touch UI:

- All content UI would reside in an iframe under the edit UI
- Edit UI aligns to the content UI by measuring where it appears, not by inserting DOM nodes into the content

The observer is one of the few scripts still needed in the content UI to notify the edit UI when it needs to update its overlays

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you pls clarify what do you mean by Edit UI? Are you referring to the edit overlay in touch ui?

Comment: Edit bar, overlays, inline dialogs, overlay dialogs, all this stuff…

Comment: sorry for one dumb question, "All content UI would reside in an iframe under the edit UI" , why iframe, is this because in iframe truly separates html components ?